# Web API OData (OData Client v4) forward slash in key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, odata-v4

I have created an OData Web API but I am having problems looking up data where the primary key contains a forward slash.

This url returns data as expected:
**/api/SalesOrders('12345')**

But this one with the forward slash in the key fails:
**/api/SalesOrders('12345/1')**
Even when encoded:
**/api/SalesOrders('12345%2F1')**

In the error presented (see below), it looks like the final forward slash is being converted to a backslash as you would expect because it is part of the url and not in the query string:

[image]

If I use the following url instead, where the forward slash is in the querystring, then the data is returned correctly:
**/api/SalesOrders?$filter=SalesOrderNumber eq 12345/1**

If I were generating the urls myself, this wouldn't be much of an issue.
However, I am using the [OData v4 Client Code Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9b786c0e-79d1-4a50-89a5-125e57475937)

So the call in code actually looks like this:

`var salesOrder = erpClient.SalesOrders.ByKey(worksOrder.SalesOrderNumber).GetValue();`

This generates the url which contains the forward slash before the query string and thus fails.

1. Is this a known issue with the OData v4 Client?
2. Is there a setting that forces use of querystring over primary key type calls?

I can work around this by forcing the forward slash into the querystring as follows:

`var salesOrder = erpClient.SalesOrders.Where(so => so.SalesOrderNumber == "12345/1" && so.SalesOrderNumber == so.SalesOrderNumber).FirstOrDefault();`

This forces the forward slash into the querystring:
**/api/SalesOrders?$filter=SalesOrderNumber eq '450993/1' and SalesOrderNumber eq SalesOrderNumber**

This feels messy and I would like to avoid moving away from the OData v4 Client as we have several apps that already use it.

Is there anything else I can do to make this work a little neater?

**Footnote:**

I followed the process on this blog to handle special characters, but this does not include advice on how to handle the forward slash:

[using-wcf-data-service-with-restricted-characters-as-keys](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peter_qian/archive/2010/05/25/using-wcf-data-service-with-restricted-characrters-as-keys.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [ODataPathAndSlashEscapeSample](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/ODataPathAndSlashEscapeSample) on Github. The basic idea is to subclass [DefaultODataPathHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.routing.defaultodatapathhandler(v=vs.118).aspx) and override the `Parse` method. Then provide an instance of your custom path handler to the [MapODataServiceRoute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn725914(v=vs.118).aspx) method in your Web API configuration code.

Comment: Updated link for [ODataPathAnsSlashEscapeSample](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/samples-archive-2018/WebApi/v4/ODataPathAndSlashEscapeSample)

Answer (score 3):

This might [help](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-22#bug-fixes) anyone looking for a similar solution, just under the 'OData Routing' section...

...To prevent this error, your client should use the double escape sequences for slash (%252F) and backslash (%255C)....

Answer (score 0):

Probably odata is messing up because it can be read litraly 
even if it is encoded, my opinion is you must  send parameters as an object in the request content.
You can see better http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/12/08/function-amp-action-in-web-api-v2-2-for-odata-v4-0-type-scenario.aspx#gist16957953

Hope this help

Comment: Submitting a POST request to a function or action would certainly avoid the issue as the data would be in the request body. It would be nice if there were something I could do server side so I didn't have to create a GetByKey[POST] action for all my entities individually.  I'll look into this.