# How to allow special characters in OData unbound function when string parameter is passed?

Tags: odata, microsoft-odata

I am creating an unbound function into an OData 18.2 v4 service in .net. The function is declared as follows:

WebApi Route Config:

```
modelBuilder
   .Function("MyFunction1")
   .ReturnsCollection<string>()
   .Parameter<string>("parameter1");
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("MyFunction1(parameter1={value1})")]
public IHttpActionResult MyFunction1([FromODataUri] string value1)
{
    return Ok(MyFunction2(value1));
}



/Test/Default.MyFunction1(value1='HV / PD Testing')
```

- how can I escape / Forward slash

Comment: Try [double-escaping it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40393737/134204) as `%252F`. The problem is that the slash is part of the URL's resource path itself, not a query parameter.

Comment: <h3>HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found</h3>
  <h4>The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.

Comment: Just `%2F` ? From [the specs](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752335) `http://host/service/Categories('Smartphone%2FTablet')` should be valid while `http://host/service/Categories('Smartphone/Tablet')` isn't. In the past double-escaping was needed because Web API itself translated `%2F` as a slash, before the query got to OData

Comment: I tried %2F but it still not working /Test/Default.MyFunction1(value1='HV %2F PD Testing') I am still getting an error

Comment: %2F is just working fine with odata filter query like this  -> Test/?$filter=Status eq 1 and DocNo eq 'AB%2F00096' but not with unbound function

Comment: What error? The actual error matters. Failing to find a match because of extra whitespace isn't the same as the server rejecting the URL itself. Which OData version are you using? ASP.NET Core or ASP.NET Framework?

Comment: The latest [Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/) version is 8.2, not 18.2. Which one are you using? There may a related issue in the Github repo of whatever library you use

Comment: I am getting Server Error in '/' Application.     <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>

 <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

  <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been
  removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make
  sure that it is spelled correctly.
  <br><br>     Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4494.0

Comment: <!-- 
[HttpException]
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetPhysicalPath(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData()
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetConfig(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CustomErrorsSection.GetSettings(HttpContext context, Boolean canThrow)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.ReportRuntimeError(Exception e, Boolean canThrow, Boolean localExecute)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.ReportRuntimeErrorIfExists(RequestNotificationStatus& status)
-->

Comment: tried  this configuration but it did not help  config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii;

Comment: What packages and versions are you using? `ASP.NET Version:4.8.4494.0` means you're using ASP.NET Framework, not Core, so you're using an older OData version. Which one?

Comment: Microsoft.Data.OData 5.8.3.0 , ASP.NET Version:4.8.4494.0

Comment: Do you *have* to use .NET Framework? All new development, both for the web infrastructure and and OData, goes into ASP.NET Core and .NET Core. The problems you have may already be fixed.

Comment: [Microsoft.Data.OData is deprecated since 2021](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData) due to critical bugs. You shouldn't use it.

Comment: For .NET Framework the correct package is [Microsoft.AspNet.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/) currently at 7.7.0, released in June 2023

Comment: sure I am going to discuss with my manager about you have told me but currently I am still stuck with my problem

Comment: There's a related GH issue in the [OData.net](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/735) site. Seems this was fixed in the past allowing `%2F` to work but broke later and may still exist in ASP.NET Core. One of the workarounds suggested is to use a [parameter alias](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_ParameterAliases), eg `.MyFunction1(value1=@value)?@value='HV %2F PD Testing'`. Didn't know that's possible

Comment: http://server/Sales.GetEmployeesByManager(ManagerID=@p1)?@p1=3 ,  I followed your instructions and thanks it is working fine but how can I pass Multiple parameter i have Id and Name passing to Unbound function